# How do you programmatically add a homebox block from one homebox page to another?

Tags: 7, dashboard

I have 2 homebox pages and would like to add a homebox block from homebox PAGE_A to PAGE_B programmatically when the user clicks a button. Ideally, this would clone the box from PAGE_A to PAGE_B.